# Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls

Tags: django, importerror

I get this error.

```
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
```

And its pointing to his line.

```
<a href="{% url auth_login %}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
```

I'm using django-registration.

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {"template": "home.html",}, name="home"),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

And I have added it in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Have you put that in `INSTALLED_APPS` and updated `urls.py` ?

Comment: Please, post full stacktrace. Also, what's the relative path to urls.py from the project root, and what's settings.ROOT_URLCONF ? (from django.conf import settings; print settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

Comment: actually it worked fine the first time. After restarting the system it shows this error. Now none of the urls are working

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF is myproject.urls

Comment: Can you import myproject.urls from manage.py shell ?